# PHP счётчик кликов для авторизованных пользователей

Tags: php

Существует код, который считывает количество нажатий на кнопку "end" для авторизованных пользователей. Проблема такова, что используя сессии информция не сохраняется после закрытия браузера. А мне нужно вести статистику для каждого пользователя и после закрытия браузера. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?
Временно решила проблему тем, что продлила жизнь сессий на 27 лет, но это, как выпонимаете, не решение

```
$expire = 9999*24*3600; // We choose duration

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $expire);

session_start(); //We start the session 

setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$expire);
```

P.S. задача вроде бы простая, но я чайник.

```
$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                // if counter is not set, set to zero
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
                        $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
                    }

                    // if button is pressed, increment counter
                    if(isset($_POST['end'])) {
                        ++$_SESSION['counter'];
                        $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
                        $query = "UPDATE `statistics` SET `total` = '$counter' WHERE `parent_user_id` = '$userID'";
                        $query_run = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                        if ($query_run) {
                                echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("data updated") </script>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("data not updated") </script>';
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. При чем здесь сессии, если речь идет о записи в бд? Судя по всему здесь нужно `SET total = total+1` безо всяких сессий

Comment: Вы мой спаситель. Спасибо за ответ. Кстати, как закрыть вопрос?